# How do I compare the value in a cell (date formant) to today's date in a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
firstDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getRange(1,5).getValue());
if (firstDate > Today()) {
spreadsheet.getRange('E2:E').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    spreadsheet.getRange('E1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('F1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    spreadsheet.getRange('E2').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('F2:U32').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
}
```

The method is not the critical part here, I am having trouble getting the IF statement to work. I have looked at several examples and the code I have here is one of the examples but none of them are working for me.

Comment: Generally with dates in JS, I would compared their .getTime() values, which gives the milliseconds since January 1, 1970 and is easier to compare. Comparing .getTime() results is useful in throwing an error if one of the two things I am comparing isn't a date object.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to change `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet` to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` as `.getActiveSpreadsheet()` is a function.

Depending on the format of the date in your cell, you can either call:

```js
firstDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(1,5).getValue().getTime() 
var Today = new Date()
if (firstDate > Today.getTime(){
  //code
}
```

or you can pass the value into a new date before comparing:

```js
firstDate = new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(1,5).getValue())
if (firstDate = Today()){
  //code
}
```